# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Backbone Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on my `@template` even though I defined `@template` using Underscore's `_.template()`

```
IntroProject.Views.Posts ||= {}

class IntroProject.Views.Posts.IndexView extends Backbone.View

  el: '#posts'

  template: _.template( $('#home-post-template').html() ) if $('#home-post-template').length

  initialize: ->
    @collection.bind "reset", ->
      @render()
    , @

  render: ->
    @collection.each (post) ->
      console.log @template( post.attributes )
    @
```

when I do `console.log @template` I get `undefined` if called in the render function. When I call `console.log @template` from within the `initialize` even, I get

```
function (data) {
      return render.call(this, data, _);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the `context` argument when calling `each`:

```
@collection.each (post) ->
  console.log @template( post.attributes )
```

so `@` is probably `window` when you say `@tempate(post.attributes)`. Specify the desired `context` when calling `each`:

```
@collection.each (post) ->
  console.log @template(post.attributes)
, @
```

or use a [fat-arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) with the callback:

```
@collection.each (post) =>
  console.log @template(post.attributes)
```

Comment: Yup I just found the answer already by the time I looked back to this question.